# Como hacer un select con mysql y php desde una modal?

Tags: php, mysqli

Tengo un modal que abre a partir de un botón el cual viene con el id del post. Este id lo almaceno en un input type "hidden",en el modal.

Mi problema es al tener este campo ya cargado con el id de post seleccionado ¿Como puedo hacer un filtrado de datos desde una BD utilizando el valor de ese campo?

este es el input:

```
<input type="hidden" id="obtenerIdPost"  name="idC">
```

**PHP**

Como pueden ver la consulta no esta completa ya que necesito cargar el valor del campo en una variable,para hacer el filtrado.

```
<?php

$query_buscar_posts = mysqli_query($conn, " SELECT * FROM comentarios WHERE id_post = ") or die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($conn));

  while ($posts_filas = mysqli_fetch_array($query_buscar_posts)) {

          $contenido2  = $posts_filas['contenido'];

       echo ' <p class="aaaaa"> '.$posts_filas['contenido'].'</p>';



        }

        ?>
```

Comment: Empieza a informarte como usar `ajax` con `PHP`, hay un montón de tutoriales ahí fuera...

Comment: En realidad se de lo que hablas.y tengo algunos ejemplos funcionando con ajax

Comment: @aldanux Ya lo hice.Es muy facil.Yo tenia un codigo aqui que lo utilizaba para hacer INSERT,pero estaba confundido en como hacer SELECT .

Comment: Perfecto... me alegro que lo hayas conseguido! Sería bueno si puedes contestar a tu misma pregunta. Saludos

Comment: @aldanux Ya la he contestado.Y gracias por no darme código. Porque?Porque he aprendido algo nuevo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Y aqui esta mi solucion:

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" id="obtenerIdPost" name="idC">
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){

   $(document).on("click", ".comentarPosts", function () {

       document.getElementById("cajacoments").style.display = 'block';
       var Id = $(this).data('id');
       $('#obtenerIdPost').val( Id );   
       alert(Id);
       var datos = 'idPost='+ Id ;

       $.ajax({
           type:'POST',
           url:'comentarios.php',
           data:datos,
           success:function(result){

               $("#div1").html(result);
           }
      });
   });
});
</script>
```

**PHP**

```
include('conexion.php');

$id_post = $_POST['idPost'];

$query_buscar_posts = mysqli_query($conn, " SELECT * 
                                            FROM comentarios 
                                            WHEREid_post = $id_post  ") or die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($conn));

while ($posts_filas = mysqli_fetch_array($query_buscar_posts)) {

    // code...
    $contenido2  = $posts_filas['contenido'];         
    echo ' <p class="aaaaa"> '.$posts_filas['contenido'].'</p>';
} 
?>
```